# How to select the least count of items in fluent nHibernate via a linq query?

Tags: linq, fluent-nhibernate

So I got a fluent nHibernate table like this:

```
public class AnsweredQuestionDb
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionDb Question { get; set; }
    public virtual AnswerDb Answer { get; set; }

}
```

QuestionDb and AnswerDb are other fluent nHibernate tables.

So I want to select the least answered Question. So if Question A was ansered 3 times and Question B,C and D where answerd 4 times the result should be Question A.

This is the point i am actually working with:

```
var leastAnswerdQuestion = (from t in m_dbSession.Query<AnsweredQuestionDb>()
                            group t.Id by t.Question into groups
                            select groups.ToList().Sum()).ToList()[0];
```

but this throws an exception and has no or order by inside. Is this even possible to do in one query?

I hope it is clear what I want to do.

I assume in sql this will look like this:

```
SELECT Question_id, count(Question_id)
FROM AnsweredQuestionDb
GROUP BY Question_id
ORDER By count(Question_id)
```

Comment: Why are you using `Sum` instead of `Count()`? Do you need the inner `ToList()`? Aren't you missing an `OrderBy`?

Comment: yes i do miss a order by. This is because I dont know how to do this in linq. All the other tries I did not even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of Svyatoslav Danyliv I created this:

Of course this is not perfect but it serves the purpurse:

```
QuestionDb nextQuestion = null;
var grouped =  (from t in m_dbSession.Query<AnsweredQuestionDb>()
               group t by t.Question.Id into g
               orderby g.Count()
               select new
               {
                   QuestionId = g.Key,
                   Count = g.Count()
               }).ToList();

var keys = grouped.Select(o => o.QuestionId).ToList();
var notAnswered = (from t in m_dbSession.Query<QuestionDb>()
                   where 
                   !keys.Contains(t.Id)
                   select t).ToList().First();

if (notAnswered != null)
{
    nextQuestion = notAnswered;
}
else
{
    if (grouped.Count() == 0)
    {
        nextQuestion = (from t in m_dbSession.Query<QuestionDb>()
                        select t).ToList().First();
    }
    else
    {
        var leastAnsweredId = grouped
            .OrderBy(x => x.Count)
            .Select(x => x.QuestionId)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        nextQuestion = (from t in m_dbSession.Query<QuestionDb>()
                        where t.Id == leastAnsweredId
                        select t).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So write LINQ query as a SQL:

```cs
var grouped = 
   from t in m_dbSession.Query<AnsweredQuestionDb>()
   group t by t.Question.Id into g
   select new 
   {
      QuestionId = g.Key,
      Count = g.Count()
   };

var leastAnsweredId = grouped
   .OrderBy(x => x.Count)
   .Select(x => x.QuestionId)
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: ok. Thanks a very lot! This is my accepted answer until I am able to solve some issues (which I was not thinking of before): 1. The answer does not work when the table AnsweredQuestionDb is empty. 2. The answer gives the "least answered Question witch was at least answerd once". So all the questions which were not answered (=have no entries in "AnsweredQuestionDb") are ignored. But this is is a problem I can solve by my own. Im very greatful for this answer!